# Sabre Web Services - Property Description Service Auth Error - ERR.SWS.CLIENT.VALIDATION_FAILED

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap-client, sabre

I'm trying to make a call to the HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ Sabre Web Service using C#. I've gotten other APIs to work with similar code but I keep getting the same Client Validation Failed error, even after retrieving a valid security token.

I think I'm missing some small piece in the proxy model, which is below.

Search Criteria Object:

```
HotelSearchCriteria searchCriteria = new HotelSearchCriteria
            {
                hotelCode = "1191",
                inDate = "8-22",
                outDate = "8-25"
            };
```

And then the proxy class:

```
public class HotelPropertyDescriptionReq
{
    private HotelPropertyDescriptionService service;
    private HotelPropertyDescriptionRQ req;
    public HotelPropertyDescriptionRS response;
    public string xmlResponse;
    public bool searchPerformed = false;

    public HotelPropertyDescriptionReq()
    {
        //parameterless constructor for serialization
    }

    public HotelPropertyDescriptionReq(SessionToken token, HotelSearchCriteria searchCriteria)
    {
        //argument validation - must have a location of some sort and some dates for search to work. Throw exception here if none found
        if (searchCriteria.hotelCode == null && searchCriteria.cityCode == null)
        {
            //no search can take place if this is null...send back an empty response with searchPerformed == fals
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot search hotel availability without hotelCode or cityCode");

        }
        else if (searchCriteria.inDate == null || searchCriteria.outDate == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot serach hotel availability without inDate and outDate");
        }
        //MessageHeader
        MessageHeader mHeader = new MessageHeader();

        PartyId[] pId = { new PartyId() };
        pId[0].Value = "SWS";

        From from = new From();
        from.PartyId = pId;

        To to = new To();
        to.PartyId = pId;

        mHeader.Action = "HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ";
        mHeader.version = "2.3.0";
        mHeader.Service = new Service()
        {
            Value = mHeader.Action
        };
        mHeader.ConversationId = token.conversationID;
        mHeader.CPAId = token.ipcc;
        mHeader.From = from;
        mHeader.To = to;

        mHeader.MessageData = new MessageData()
        {
            Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString(),
        };


        //Security
        //Security sec = new Security();
        Security1 sec = new Security1();
        sec.BinarySecurityToken = token.securityToken;


        //Service
        service = new HotelPropertyDescriptionService();
        service.MessageHeaderValue = mHeader;
        //service.SoapVersion = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapProtocolVersion.Soap11;
        service.Security = sec;

        //request
        req = new HotelPropertyDescriptionRQ();

        req.AvailRequestSegment = new HotelPropertyDescriptionRQAvailRequestSegment();
        req.AvailRequestSegment.GuestCounts = new HotelPropertyDescriptionRQAvailRequestSegmentGuestCounts();
        req.AvailRequestSegment.GuestCounts.Count = "1";

        req.AvailRequestSegment.HotelSearchCriteria = new HotelPropertyDescriptionRQAvailRequestSegmentHotelSearchCriteria();
        req.AvailRequestSegment.HotelSearchCriteria.Criterion = new HotelPropertyDescriptionRQAvailRequestSegmentHotelSearchCriteriaCriterion();
        req.AvailRequestSegment.HotelSearchCriteria.Criterion.HotelRef = new HotelPropertyDescriptionRQAvailRequestSegmentHotelSearchCriteriaCriterionHotelRef();

        req.AvailRequestSegment.HotelSearchCriteria.Criterion.HotelRef.HotelCode = searchCriteria.hotelCode;

        req.AvailRequestSegment.TimeSpan = new HotelPropertyDescriptionRQAvailRequestSegmentTimeSpan();
        req.AvailRequestSegment.TimeSpan.Start = searchCriteria.inDate;
        req.AvailRequestSegment.TimeSpan.End = searchCriteria.outDate;

        string requestXML = Serializer.toXML(req);
        string headerXML = Serializer.toXML(mHeader);


        //send the request
        try

        {
            response = service.HotelPropertyDescriptionRQ(req);
            searchPerformed = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the resulting Soap-Request? Makes more sense to debug from there.

Comment: I used Pastebin to throw the XML up online since it won't fit in the comments - let me know if this is not the most helpful way of providing it.

Thanks for all your input!

https://pastebin.com/9TPZXaWg

Comment: I dont know where the "-" come from in your request, but they have to definately go. Looks a little bit malformed overall. Will add a working request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working request - your payload looks a little bit diffrent then the one  created by you. Just try to replicate this - need to set the PCC and securitycredentials:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="2.0">
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">1212</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">2323</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>YOURPCCHERE</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:ConversationId>XXX-dd74-4500-99d6-1e746b8876cc1507217090989</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service eb:type="OTA">HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>1001</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2016-06-07T10:00:01</eb:Timestamp>
                <eb:TimeToLive>2017-06-06T23:59:59</eb:TimeToLive>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary" valueType="String">YOURSECRETHERE</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <HotelPropertyDescriptionRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ReturnHostCommand="false" TimeStamp="2015-11-30T12:00:00-06:10" Version="2.3.0">
            <AvailRequestSegment>
             <GuestCounts Count="1"/>
                <HotelSearchCriteria>
                    <Criterion>
                        <HotelRef HotelCode="0022426" UnitOfMeasure="KM"/>
                    </Criterion>
                </HotelSearchCriteria>
                <POS>
                    <Source>
                        <CompanyName Division="BER"/>
                    </Source>
                </POS>
                <TimeSpan End="04-24" Start="04-22" />
            </AvailRequestSegment>
        </HotelPropertyDescriptionRQ>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: This is great - thank you for your response. I think the dashes are artifacts from the way I was copy/pasting from VS. I reworked some of the request and added the elements to the POS level of the request and it seems to be returning results now. The documentation does list both POS and Source as Mandatory, but I have absolutely no idea what the CompanyName and Division members refer to as I don't know the equivalent Sabre host command for that. The Sabre Sample payloads don't include any POS level information in the request so that is very confusing to me.

Comment: Yeah Sabre docs are not that great - for division you should use the city code of the "agency"/ticketing partner in our case BER for Berlin

Comment: Thanks for that info. Those nodes are listed as mandatory, but none of the sample payloads they list in their current documentation include it (http://webservices.sabre.com/drc/servicedoc/HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ_v2.3.0_Sample_Payloads.xml). Frustrating to be sure.

Comment: Welcome do developing with sabre webservices/integrating any GDS ;)